# How to convert ffmpeg 24 bit flac to 16 bit alac?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, conversion, flac, alac

I was needing help with the command to turn a 24 bit flac to 16 bit alac.

To turn 24 bit flac to 16 bit flac:

`ffmpeg -i input.flac -sample_fmt s16 -ar 48000 output.flac`

To turn flac to alac:

`ffmpeg -i input.flac -vn -acodec alac output.m4a`

I could try to pipe, but was wondering if there was anyway to marry these together into wedded bliss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg input.flac -sample_fmt s16p -ar 48000 -c:a alac output.m4a
```

ALAC requires a *planar* sample format (`s16p`) in which each channel data is in its own plane, instead of the regular, *packed* `s16` format.

When you run the two commands separately, ffmpeg will helpfully convert `s16` to `s16p` for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I was getting errors with your command, but found if I ran `ffmpeg -i input.flac -sample_fmt s16p -ar 48000 -vn -acodec alac output.m4a` I was getting the result I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: Does your input contain album art? If so you may need `-vn`. Next time please always include the full, uncut command line output you got when running your ffmpeg command.